# Provision a third-party (Custom) service application using powershell

Tags: service-application

I am trying to automate deployment of a custom service application created by a third party. The current process is to go to Central Admin -> App Management -> Manage Service Apps and then create a New Service Application of the type, the creation form asks information on databases and stuff.

My question is will the custom service's developer have to have taken additional steps to allow provisioning using PowerShell Commands (perhaps build a PowerShell Snapin?) or all actions performed in GUI (Cerntal Admin Website) have PowerShell commands and therefore there would be some commands for the custom service. If there are then how do I discover them?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to contact the vendor/developer of the Service Application for this answer.

The ability to provision via PowerShell is a best practice, and all the Microsoft sample code of creating a service application includes this, so there is a chance they will have done so, but it's best to ask the original developer for the Cmdlet names and syntax that you need to use to provision the service app.